# Request receiving 403 in Python but working fine in browser

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I have a simple HTTP post request that works fine in browser but not in Python.

In YARC extension of Chrome, I do not add any header and it works, but not in Python. I have noticed that in Python a "User-Agent" header is probably needed but it doesn't work.

```py
import requests
    
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0',
}
response = requests.post("https://www.zara.com/es/es/shop/cart/add?ajax=true",data ={"data": "{"products":[{"datatype":"product","sku":57405364,"parentId":79374687,"quantity":1,"categoryId":0}]}",headers = headers)
```

If you try the request in an online REST client, with the URL and "`{"products":[{"datatype":"product","sku":57405364,"parentId":79374687,"quantity":1,"categoryId":0}]}`" as payload.

PS: Eventually, I get banned from the website and I get "Access Denied" even when going to the main website using Chrome browser.

PS2: I have tried in Node with the same result than in Python

**EDIT**
I have tried via web but using a website instead of a extension. With the website the request is not working.

[Chrome Extension (Works)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brvon.png)

[chrome website (Not works)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYK5k.png)

**EDIT 2**
import requests

I have done it using sessions. I have opened the site and tried to replicate the packages that are sent, and enable the request:

```
s = requests.Session()
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0'
}

first_web = s.get("https://www.zara.com", headers=headers)

pack_1 = s.get("https://cdn.cookielaw.org/consent/cadb9218-57dc-4d9d-88e2-9f60895ffd8e/cadb9218-57dc-4d9d-88e2-9f60895ffd8e.json", headers=headers)

pack_2 = s.get("https://cdn.cookielaw.org/consent/cadb9218-57dc-4d9d-88e2-9f60895ffd8e/a78fd482-5d91-40b8-94e6-abb4b5a80e69/es-es.json", headers=headers)

pack_3 = s.get("https://c.go-mpulse.net/api/config.json?key=KAZLT-VPAY6-9BKL5-JEPJR-ULDBV&d=www.zara.com&t=5367111&v=1.667.0&if=&sl=0&si=rvor2q71m4b-qmmqq0&plugins=AK,ConfigOverride,Continuity,PageParams,IFrameDelay,AutoXHR,SPA,Angular,Backbone,Ember,History,RT,CrossDomain,BW,PaintTiming,NavigationTiming,ResourceTiming,Memory,CACHE_RELOAD,Errors,TPAnalytics,UserTiming,Akamai,Early,LOGN&acao=&ak.ai=182996", headers=headers)

pack_4 = s.get("https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/6.8.0/assets/otFloatingRoundedCorner.json", headers=headers)

pack_5 = s.get("https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/6.8.0/assets/v2/otPcTab.json", headers=headers)

pack_6 = s.post("https://www.zara.com/content/fb9d7c490crn18411a51025b2bf19115",data = {"data": '{"sensor_data":"7a74G7m23Vrp0o5c9124641.66-1,2,-94,-100,Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36,uaend,12147,20030107,es-ES,Gecko,3,0,0,0,396169,3192694,1536,824,1536,864,1536,150,1536,,cpen:0,i1:0,dm:0,cwen:0,non:1,opc:0,fc:0,sc:0,wrc:1,isc:0,vib:1,bat:1,x11:0,x12:1,8324,0.18660850393,805066596346.5,0,loc:-1,2,-94,-101,do_en,dm_en,t_en-1,2,-94,-105,-1,2,-94,-102,0,-1,0,0,2108,2108,0;-1,2,-94,-108,-1,2,-94,-110,-1,2,-94,-117,-1,2,-94,-111,0,82,-1,-1,-1;-1,2,-94,-109,0,82,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1;-1,2,-94,-114,-1,2,-94,-103,-1,2,-94,-112,https://www.zara.com/-1,2,-94,-115,1,32,32,82,82,0,164,674,0,1610133192693,150,17224,0,0,2870,0,0,677,164,0,0E4BC3B6F9AC23B930A57B3AB8F99FC3~-1~YAAQ1fpxaH2L/N52AQAA6Ktq4wU1BqmcLinaILJqwTuC3F5/D44Pp/0hpXlVVK/a8CSiy/0AoBrpwDu7HFoXEP2NwenggqS402C6GPuLOiHIie0N1ddZJIhVbkbiCo0OfOjACyU88FoDZ0VxP+GV4Uy/fYpJGbUQKVqMiqC77E05iPqJuyHT/82Wn8yeZb724kwyCEDEN/4kCSlwtIwFwUOgXCJxpW7PHLIEO894htUSR9cbCVG4B3Rht9dgKlmDAdvDbsIGUNzF0tMH77V6DuQ0brrw46xrFjuVKjmaNRQjWkowTDc+xw==~-1~-1~-1,28905,938,1898254782,30261693,PiZtE,49725,105-1,2,-94,-106,9,1-1,2,-94,-119,105,71,81,80,123,131,88,69,79,62,62,63,131,736,-1,2,-94,-122,0,0,0,0,1,0,0-1,2,-94,-123,-1,2,-94,-124,-1,2,-94,-126,-1,2,-94,-127,11321144241322243122-1,2,-94,-70,73331404;1714644147;dis;,7,8;true;true;true;-60;true;24;24;true;false;-1-1,2,-94,-80,5422-1,2,-94,-116,47890440-1,2,-94,-118,81190-1,2,-94,-129,b52911bd04667ddee3bef537d2dfa06c282ce7a6d401bd534e7d5f8f53318b7d,1.25,0,,,,0-1,2,-94,-121,;132;18;0"}'}, headers=headers)

headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"
}
final_response = s.post("https://www.zara.com/es/es/shop/cart/add?ajax=true",data ={"data": '{"products":[{"datatype":"product","sku":57405364,"parentId":79374687,"quantity":1,"categoryId":0}]}'}, headers=headers)

print(response)
```

Comment: It's common for the GET you're not doing in your Python code (but which your browser has done when you browse to the site) to setup cookies required for a (successful)  POST - so you should try using a requests session to GET on the URL before then using the same session for POST with your headers.

Comment: But anyway 403 is forbidden so you'll need to authenticate. You've probably already done this in your browser. Suggest you trace a browser login and access to the page using e.g. Telerik Fiddler then replicate the headers/parameters/payload in your Python code, always using a session.

Comment: I have tried using a session but it doesn't worked. I receive the answer properly, but the post returns 403 again. Regarding the login, I have logged out from the website and the request is still working (via browser)

Comment: OK well you should persist with the session and the GET before the POST. But you need to trace a browser access and see what your code is missing. A simple way but not the easiest to use is to try tracing using the browser developer console's Network tab.

Comment: I'm almost sure that the problem is caused by what you said. I have tried to do the request in a Privacy Browsing, and it failed. Then I have opened the main site (www.zara.com) and stop it when only 6 packages have been sent, and it worked! Nevertheless, I have tried to replicate them in Python with no success

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you previously logged into the site in your browser and it "remembers" the login. When you try to do the same thing with Python code, you are not authenticated with the site, so it returns a 403 Forbidden response.

To fix the problem, you need to authenticate your request in the Python code.

Comment: This authentication is the user/pass from the site o it could be another way?

Comment: @VRG I'm not sure what you mean by "another way". You don't authenticate at all in the Python code, so "another" has nothing to do with it. You need to properly authenticate each request.

Comment: I have logged out and it still works... but only in the Chrome extension, not with a API tester website. I don't understand why this happens...

Comment: What do you mean "logged out"? Do you mean in your browser? Why does that matter? What does a Chrome extension have to do with this question about making a request in Python? That doesn't change the fact that in your Python code you need to authenticate the request to avoid the 403 error.

Comment: But I have no user or pass, how can I authenticate?

Comment: 403 is “forbidden” so clearly you need to do something more, whether that’s headers/parameters/content, or some combination. Tracing a working access from a browser is the only way to remove the guesswork.

Comment: @VRG "authenticate" might not be the right term here. More accurately, you need to form the request in such a way that it is authorized. Often this means a request that authenticates you with the system and returns a token that then you include with other requests. This is the form of authorization I'm familiar with because I implement it in systems I build myself. There are definitely other forms of authorization. As barny says, you will need to dig into how the browser does it to figure this out.

Comment: I have copied the requests in cURL and translated them to Python using a website. I have executed them all (using a session) but it doesnt work, I don't know what to do next. It seems that opening the web enable the request to run properly, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "opening the web"? Do you mean using a browser? What were the exact steps you did in the browser?